# How to pass hidden field value into my Onclick method on a button in a MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a hidden field like this in my view:

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Url)
```

then i have a form in which i'm posting the data via Ajax call like this:

```
<form id="formdata">

     <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm('@Url.RouteUrl("createAccount/"+ '@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Url)'+ )'">

</form>
```

How do i Pass the url from the hidden form into my submit function. I'm not sure if i have to use double  quotes or single  quotes around it? or is this achievable?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlHelper.HiddenFor` used for creating hidden field with specified value assigned to viewmodel binder, instead of rendering its value directly. What you need is using `Model.Url` property to pass viewmodel property into JS function like this:

```
<input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Submit"
       onclick="submitForm('@Url.RouteUrl("createAccount/" + Model.Url)')">
```

In case it returns encoded URL containing query string, use `Html.Raw()` i.e. `Html.Raw(Model.Url)`.

NB: You can use `AjaxHelper.BeginForm` to submit a form through AJAX as alternative to handling submit button `click` event & using `jQuery.ajax` with passed URL.

Comment: Thank you . much appreciated